# how can I use my macbook pro as a primary display for my mac mini?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, display, mac-mini

I want to use my Apple Mac Mini without connecting a monitor through the VGA, I have also a MacBook pro and an iPad. I want to know how I can use the MacBook pro (ideally wirelessly) to act as the display and keyboard and mouse for my Mac Mini.

Answer (score 1):

Wirelessly I think you'd have to use something like VNC, which is built-in to the Mac OS.

Maybe see https://www.realvnc.com/products/ which I've had some success with.

Alternatively, there's [Apple Remote Access](https://www.apple.com/uk/remotedesktop/), but that is more for a corporate environment & is reflected in the price.

Comment: /System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.app